# What are the analysis steps in taking raw data from Kepler to a planetary system determination

Tags: exoplanet, data-analysis, kepler

I wish to get a concise list of the analysis steps required to take raw light data from a Kepler data set of a star through the steps needed to get to an analytical determination of the existence of a planetary system (i.e. find a planet candidate in a light curve).  I would also like any software analysis tools that would be suggested for each data analysis step.  A good reference specifically outlining these steps would also be helpful.

I would first like to replicate the complete set of steps needed to corroborate the existence of a well accepted planetary system. After that I would feel confident that I could move on to analysis of some Kepler KOI data sets that NASA has published or even some data from a non-KOI entity.  I am an amateur and I realize that astronomical knowledge needs to be applied at each data step and that this might not be an automated process but the steps of this analysis would open up new areas of study for me.

I have tried to assemble the basic data analysis tools from various astronomical python sites and other light transit tool sites and get a little familiar with them but I am not clear as to the actual steps as to how these programs feed to each other.  I have looked at the NASA Kepler pipeline to see the steps but it is not clear to me what specific software they apply. I have read several papers confirming exoplanetary discoveries but from them I can't get a complete picture of the data analysis steps and software employed.

It is disappointing that the actual code listings are not presented in the papers or in a separate reference doc.  In the past (50 years ago) , it was required to publish code listings in reports and references to the code listings in any papers.  But, this discussion is probably another subject.

Comment: Not clear what you mean? The steps taken to find a planet candidate in a light curve? Or the steps taken to determine the existence of a planetary system? I guess the former, since the latter involves (usually) spectroscopy and other techniques. This paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6550 contains extensive references to transit detection algorithms.

Comment: It appears that Rob Jeffries, who is quickly becoming a hero of mine, has answered this, but I would like to comment. A large chunk of "Kepler" planets that were changed from "candidate" status to "confirmed" status were part of multiple planet "system candidates". Statistical analysis provided a high enough probability that these candidates were real that they have now been considered "confirmed".

Comment: @RobJeffries I went ahead and edited. The user hasn't been back in a while, so I don't think we have to worry about conflicts with their intent.